# SoapUI to postman

Tags: postman, soapui

I have a WSDL that connects fine with SoapUI, now this settings are, Authentication type No Authorization, username and password, when I run it works great I get what I wanted, but now I need this on postman.

I imported the WSDKL file, but where do I put the username and password since the Authentication type is set to No Authorization, if I change the No Authorization to basic on postman it enabled me the option to enter username and password, but I get error 500 since the WSDL was configured Authentication type No Authorization.

I use postman to run all my tests then use the export code in php-curl to be use on websites.

the soapUI
[image: soapui property settings]

Actually is working just fine on SoapUI, but can't get this to work on postman since I do not know where to enter username and password.